# Simpy resource capacity management

Tags: python, simpy

I'm developing a discrete even simulator for a very long, multiply re-entrant manufacturing process (parts go through a number of tools in a certain sequence, and often come back to the same tool multiple times). The overall flow of the program is working nicely and give the expected queue depths, congestion points etc, under various build plan scenarios. The challenge I have not yet found a way to resolve is that of a tool with capacity >1 which may run ,multiple parts at a time but it must start them all at the same time (i.e., they may run in a chamber or a bath for example that cannot be opened/accessed when one part is running to add another).

Thus, I'm looking for a way to implement a tool with, say capacity=4, so that at the start of a run if there are 4 or more items in its queue, it'll load 4 of them and run them, but if there is only one part at time zero, that one part runs and anything that comes into the queue while that one part is running has to wait until the run is over.

My code is rather too long and complicated to illustrate the problem, well but the problem is well-described by the famous simpy "fueling station" example (code below). The behavior of that I'm trying to get rid of is expressed in this code. That is, the fuel station has capacity = 2, a car comes up and takes one of the slots, then some time later another car arrives and takes the remaining slot. That's great for gas pumps but I'm trying to block later users from gaining access once a run is launched.

I could envision giving the tool a property like self.status and set status to 'busy' or some such thing when the tool is in use, or perhaps use self.res.users in some way to do that but I wonder if there is some more natively simpy way of getting my tools to behave in the desired way.

Thanks!

```
import itertools
import random

import simpy


RANDOM_SEED = 42
GAS_STATION_SIZE = 200     # liters
THRESHOLD = 10             # Threshold for calling the tank truck (in %)
FUEL_TANK_SIZE = 50        # liters
FUEL_TANK_LEVEL = [5, 25]  # Min/max levels of fuel tanks (in liters)
REFUELING_SPEED = 2        # liters / second
TANK_TRUCK_TIME = 300      # Seconds it takes the tank truck to arrive
T_INTER = [30, 300]        # Create a car every [min, max] seconds
SIM_TIME = 1000            # Simulation time in seconds


def car(name, env, gas_station, fuel_pump):
    """A car arrives at the gas station for refueling.

    It requests one of the gas station's fuel pumps and tries to get the
    desired amount of gas from it. If the stations reservoir is
    depleted, the car has to wait for the tank truck to arrive.

    """
    fuel_tank_level = random.randint(*FUEL_TANK_LEVEL)
    print('%s arriving at gas station at %.1f' % (name, env.now))
    with gas_station.request() as req:
        start = env.now
        # Request one of the gas pumps
        yield req

        # Get the required amount of fuel
        liters_required = FUEL_TANK_SIZE - fuel_tank_level
        yield fuel_pump.get(liters_required)

        # The "actual" refueling process takes some time
        yield env.timeout(liters_required / REFUELING_SPEED)

        print('%s finished refueling in %.1f seconds.' % (name,
                                                          env.now - start))


def gas_station_control(env, fuel_pump):
    """Periodically check the level of the *fuel_pump* and call the tank
    truck if the level falls below a threshold."""
    while True:
        if fuel_pump.level / fuel_pump.capacity * 100 < THRESHOLD:
            # We need to call the tank truck now!
            print('Calling tank truck at %d' % env.now)
            # Wait for the tank truck to arrive and refuel the station
            yield env.process(tank_truck(env, fuel_pump))

        yield env.timeout(10)  # Check every 10 seconds


def tank_truck(env, fuel_pump):
    """Arrives at the gas station after a certain delay and refuels it."""
    yield env.timeout(TANK_TRUCK_TIME)
    print('Tank truck arriving at time %d' % env.now)
    amount = fuel_pump.capacity - fuel_pump.level
    print('Tank truck refuelling %.1f liters.' % amount)
    yield fuel_pump.put(amount)


def car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump):
    """Generate new cars that arrive at the gas station."""
    for i in itertools.count():
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(*T_INTER))
        env.process(car('Car %d' % i, env, gas_station, fuel_pump))


# Setup and start the simulation
print('Gas Station refuelling')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# Create environment and start processes
env = simpy.Environment()
gas_station = simpy.Resource(env, 2)
fuel_pump = simpy.Container(env, GAS_STATION_SIZE, init=GAS_STATION_SIZE)
env.process(gas_station_control(env, fuel_pump))
env.process(car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump))

# Execute!
env.run(until=SIM_TIME)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems to me each car grabs a pump, but what you really want is a pump to grab up to two cars at a time.  So you need a process that does the batching.  Here is a quick and dirty batch processor.  I use a store for the input queue, and when every my yield get() gets a first entity, I check the queue for up to capacity more entities to process,  What this yield really does is cause my process to wait when the queue is empty

```
"""
    A simple example of a process that process entities in batches

    Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

def batch_process(env, ent_q, next_q, max_cap):
    """
        grabs up to max_cap of entites and processes them
    """

    while True:

        # use a yield to wait when queue is empty 
        ent_1 = yield ent_q.get()

        # grabs up to capacity -1 more
        p_batch = [ent_1] + ent_q.items[:(max_cap - 1)]
        ent_q.items = ent_q.items[(max_cap - 1):]

        print(f'{env.now:.2f} grabbed {len(p_batch)} entites leaving {len(ent_q.items)} left in queue')

        # do the processing
        yield env.timeout(10)

        # send entitles to next stop
        next_q.items = next_q.items + p_batch

def gen_ents(env, q):
    """
        Generate the arrival of entities

        arrival profile starts slow
        has a peek
        then nothing which drains the queue
        and puts the process in a wait mode
        another peek

    """
    for _ in range(10):
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,6))
        q.put(object())
    for _ in range(15):
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,3))
        q.put(object())
    yield env.timeout(50)
    for _ in range(15):
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,3))
        q.put(object())
    for _ in range(10):
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,7))
        q.put(object())


# boot up model
random.seed(100)
env = simpy.Environment()

process_q = simpy.Store(env)
exit_q = simpy.Store(env)

env.process(gen_ents(env, process_q))
env.process(batch_process(env, process_q, exit_q, 4))

env.run(1000)
print(f'Simulation has finish a time {env.now}')
```

Comment: Thanks very much Michael - very slick and much appreciated. I might not have expressed it in sufficient detail, but the behavior I'm looking for is for the tool to run partly empty if there is nothing else in the queue and if something else enters the queue while the tool is running, it must wait until the partially loaded tool completes its cycle and then at that point the n=capacity highest priority items in the queue would get run, and again if there are less than capacity at that time only the m<n items would run immediately and hold new requests in abeyance until the ongoing run completes

Comment: I think the framework you have provided can get me there though - let me spend some time with it, I'll post back if I can get it to work with that behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing.  When it time to start a batch it grabs up to 4 entities, not waiting for more entities to show up.  process the batch, then grab another batch.  The way I use the yield get() to check if the queue is empty may be a bit confusing, but it also handles the case when the queue is empty and needs to wait.

If you provide a trace of events on how it should work I can try again

Comment: If you look at the log, the first number is the batch size, showing that batch less then the max is being run.  The first line in the log shows when the first entity arrives in the system, gets grab in a batch of 1.  while that batch gets processed, other entities arrive and get queued until the second batch starts.

Comment: Indeed it does have exactly the desired behavior and I have accepted the answer. The challenge I'm having with implementation is that in my code the "Tool" is realized as a resource, not a store. In fact to facilitate implementation of unplanned breakdowns and preventative maintenance  I modeled it as a preemptive resource. The way I'm looking at this tt seems that in order to implement this methodology I'd need to associate a store with each tool and place jobs into the store instead of the tool's queue.

Comment: ... and use a function like batch_process to manage moving requests from the store to the queue. That'd be a big change to my program I think and I wonder if there is another way to approach that - perhaps using the tool (resource) queue directly? I'm experimenting with that now - will post something once I get it working but it's slow going - meanwhile welcome any thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: So I do not thing you want to create a batch unless a machine is ready to start.  The two options is to expand this code to act as a broker.  Where the first step in the loop is to get a machine, then make the batch, then kick off the machine process async (no yield).  The other option is to make this process into a machine class where the machine is making request for batches instead of getting requested by something else.  The new class would then also have a process for breakdowns that would stop the machine from making batch requests until fixed.  I have done both in the past.

Comment: I hardly ever use resources.  I often need a machine with some sort of behavior, like break downs, or to record stats for the individual machine.  flipping things around where instead of work requesting machines to machines requesting work often fixes all sorts of design issues and Stores make good queues between processes.

Comment: Yes! The tool class is the architecture I have now, and I think I now see a path to using the store object to manage this. I think that will actually solve some other problems I've yet to deal with. I'll post a minimal example once I have it all working. I think that is days away due to conflicting projects but I will post back with something working. Thanks much for your thoughts on this!